# Creating a Roslyn Code Analyser to run against a 4.5.2 project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5, roslyn-code-analysis

I have created a Roslyn code analyzer in Visual Studio 2017 (using the "Analyzer with code fix template targeting 4.5.2,  It creates the project targeting dot net standard 1.3) and it works fine against a test project using framework 4.6.1.

I have tried to use this analyzer against a project written against 4.5.2 and it is giving me an error:

> An instance of analyzer .... can not be created from ... : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.4.0.0...' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

I believe that is because dot net standard 1.3 is supported by 4.6.x.  Is there anyway to get my code to target 4.5.2?  I know that there are Roslyn Analyzers that target 4.5.2.

Many thanks in advance.